# Codeigniter single quotes when retrieve API issue

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-restserver

I added some data like these "`I&#39;m completely drunk, drunk`"

And my CI web app works fine but when I retrieve APi it shows like that only..

Can you tell me how to display like this `I'm completely drunk, drunk`..

We can't change Android app side. Please provide a solution in the API. Piece of code for your reference..

Controller:

```
$allvals=$this->allmodel->videochapterslession($id,$chap);
 $this->response(array("status"=>"Success","data"=>$allvals), REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
```

Model:

```
public function videochapterslession($id){
$this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('caption');
 $this->db->where('video_id',$id);
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $row = $query->result_array();
            return $row;
        }
        else{
        return false;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use html_entity_decode function

```
$s = 'I&#39;m completely drunk, drunk';
echo html_entity_decode($s);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply,,But is retrieve all fields and display..please see the model and controller

Comment: @selva loop the row and use this function for that value